# Quickly create a large file on FAT

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, filesystems, fat32

What is the quickest way to create a large file on a FAT MicroSD in Windows? All solutions until now have shown methods that result in a sparse file, but I need all sectors allocated upfront (since it will be used by a datalogger).Currently I just write several gigabytes of zeroes, but it takes a long time.

EDIT: It seems that to comply with FAT specification Windows will have to allocate all data blocks and zero-initialize them, because of the "cluster chaining" FAT does. So I guess I'm asking for the impossible, however I will leave the question open just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Alex is right in saying that it is the fastest way in terms of execution time, but it is non trivial to write to a FAT. My understanding is that you will have to deal with sector size and fragmentation. Here is a [open source FAT32 implementation](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) that LGTM.

The fastest way in terms of how little code you need to write is [option 1 in this Raymond Chen blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/22/10215053.aspx).

In short :

1. Create the file
2. Seek to end
3. Write a single byte

Bonus : it works on NTFS also (I use it one application I'm working on).

Answer (score 0):

The quickest will be to access the sectors with the FAT control data directly and allocate a long enough chain of clusters and make a directory entry for the file and make it point to the first cluster of the chain. This avoids writing gigabytes of zeroes. This should be a trivial task if you start out with empty pre-formatted media and do not need to preserve any previously written data. You can just hard-code the contents of the control data areas and avoid FAT parsing.

I don't remember how exactly you can get such low-level/raw access in Windows. I think you just need to open the device volume (or the physical device) and then it will be accessible as raw data. See details in the description of [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. Your app may need to have special access rights for this on Vista+.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create the file (using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx)) and set the size of the file afterwards, using [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx). Not sure whether Windows zero-initializes the sectors though. If I remember correctly, it did not on FAT32 partitions under Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll be useful to try [fsutil](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788058.aspx):

> fsutil file [createnew] (FileName) (Length)